# Spark Graphx flatten hierarchical data from Leaf to Root

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am exploring Spark Graphx to flatten hierarchical tree from Leaf to root. My dataset is stored tabular format with child and parent columns. There are many disjoint trees like this.

[image]

**Expected result**

```
2,7,8
5,7,8
3,4,8
```

I have gone through the GraphX wiki and still unable to figureout the approach. Any suggestions or Psuedo approach to solve this would be appreciated.

**Sample Code-**

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx.{Edge, Graph, VertexId}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
object MSTGraphLauncher extends SparkSessionWrapper{
  import spark.implicits._
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val users: RDD[(VertexId, (String))] =
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1L, ("rxin")),(2L, ("rxin")),(3L, ("rxin")),(4L, ("rxin")), (5L, ("jgonzal")),
        (6L, ("franklin")), (7L, ("istoica")),(8L, ("istoica"))))
    val relationships: RDD[Edge[String]] =
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Edge(2L, 7L, "advisor"),Edge(5L, 7L, "advisor"),Edge(7L,8L, "advisor"),Edge(3L, 4L, "colleague"),Edge(4L, 8L, "collab"),
        Edge(1L, 6L, "colleague")))


    val graph = Graph(users, relationships)


  }
}
```

Comment: graphx is legacy. Look at this answer I gave for on graphFrames. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067566/combining-rows-that-link-together-in-a-spark-dataframe/64078592#64078592

Comment: you can use a modified sssp algorithm like the one given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27109143/2129801)